# MAX30102 showing Heart rate: 0.00bpm / SpO2: 0%

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, i2c

I am using a MAX30102 to monitor SpO<sub>2</sub> and heart rate using the https://github.com/oxullo/Arduino-MAX30100 library and the minimal example, but it is not showing any value change.

It only shows zero and in the library tester example it is also showing a timeout error for die temperature.

I removed all 3 pull up registers and given 5 v supply.

[image: MAX30102]

Please help to get correct result; I will be thankful.

Comment: Have you used pull-up resistor with 5V?

Comment: the tester example, checks connections on the startup. are they ok ?
you have to put your finger on the sensor, but not pressing againts it, and without shakes or movements for a few seconds before the results start to change. also, you can decrease the led current (uncomment it in the example) and try again.

Answer (score 1):

To identify the issue, run I2C Scanner and check the address of this module on the Serial Monitor.

If the I2C Scanner program is not able to detect the module, then either the module is defective or connections are wrong.

If the I2C Scanner program is able to identify the sensor, then check with other libraries.